# Delete all lines in file until line with string

Tags: python, string, file

I'm writting a script for editing a file.txt. I have a string name:

```
str_name = 'abcd'
```

My file has a lot of lines. I delete all the lines before `str_name`, and left in the file line with `str_name` and all below.

Comment: `line = file.readlines()` followed by `for line in file:` doesn't make sense. Just remove `line = file.readlines()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
file = open(local_filename, "r")
lines = file.readlines()
for line in lines:
    if str_name in line:
        print("Find")
        start = lines.index(line)
        lines = lines[start::1]
        break
    else:
        print("Not found")
file.close()
file = open(local_filename, "wt")
for line in lines:
    file.write(f"{line}")
file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid reading all of the file into memory, you can do

```
with open(local_filename, "r") as f, open(local_filename + ".new", "w") as outf:
    found = False
    for line in f:
        if str_name in line:
            found = True
        if found:
            outf.write(line)
```

– i.e. keep track whether you've found the line you need, and if you have, begin writing them into another file.

If you want, you can do an `os.rename()` at the end to replace the new file into place.